# How to prevent Sharepoint Office 365 online to add most viewed links to navbar?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Sharepoint Office 365 automatically adds links to most viewed pages. How to prevent it. It is hard to hide every newly appeared link from Site Settings > Navigation Settings. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could delete `Recent` node from Left Navigation via *SharePoint CSOM API*.

> Prerequisites: [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

The following example demonstrates how to delete `Recent` node from Left Navigation in PowerShell:

```
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 


Function Get-Context([string]$Url,[string]$Username,[string]$Password){
   $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
   $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
   $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
   $ctx.Credentials = $credentials
   return $ctx
}


Function Delete-NavigationNode([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$Web,[string]$NodeTitle){
   $ctx = $Web.Context
   $nodes = $Web.Navigation.QuickLaunch
   $ctx.Load($nodes)
   $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

   $node = $nodes.GetEnumerator() | where { $_.Title -eq $NodeTitle } | Select -First 1 
   $node.DeleteObject()
   $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
}



$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"
$Username = "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = ""


$ctx = Get-Context -Url $Url -Username $Username -Password $Password
Delete-NavigationNode -Web $ctx.Web -NodeTitle "Recent"
```